# Core plot:reloading/refreshing 3 pie plots in core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am adding 3 pie plots to CPTXYGraph object with identifier 1,2 3.On selecting a particular slice in a plot for eg identifier 1  the slice animates and pops out.But on selecting a slice in plot with identifier 2 that particular slice p[ops out but i also want the slice selected in plot with identifier 1 to go back to original solution.how do I achieve this?
I am using only one object of CPTXYGraph and adding three plots to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the exploded state of the pie slices somewhere. When you want to explode a slice, check to see if any other slices are already exploded and if so, bring them back in.

Comment: Hi Erick,I am not getting you, can you please tell me how can I keep track of exploded slices in different hosting view in same graph?

Comment: When you "pop out" a slice on one of the plots, save the index and the identifier in a ivar in the controller. When it's time to explode another plot, use the saved info to reset the original plot and then update the saved info to indicate the new plot and slice index.